# Rate Up and Down Button

Tags: php, javascript, html

On my site I have a rate up button, the user (who doesn't need to have an account on the website) can rate up a post/picture. I want the user to be able to rate up the content only once. However if they click on the rate up again, it should just deduct the previous rating resulting in no rating at all. So it just toggles between 1 and 0.

I know there is a way to limit by IP but that isn't the best way to go about doing this. I think there is a way to do it through the cookies, to check if the user has pressed the rate button before or something, however I'm not sure.

Would any one be able to guide me on this matter?

Comment: I don't think cookies are reliable, as anyone can clear their coockie are rate again, perhaps as much as they are willing to go

Comment: i realise that but the average user wont be doing this. However if you can suggest alternate methods it would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest IP and another field that just stores the numbers, so every week/month you can delete the IP and just update 1 number row.Doing that, can save you storing IP of hundreds of users for a sigle comment/article

Comment: lets say a few people who are on the same network like at a university or school. One person uses the rate up button, does that mean the rest of the people on the same network cant press the rate up too?

Comment: I am sorry, did you mean you wanted to create the rate function without a user account?

Comment: Yeah anyone who comes onto the site can use the rate up button they dont need to have a user account to rate things.

Comment: Well use sessions then. Since a session terminates once a user closes the browser. So, that means it is likely another user from the school. Anyone can bypass this by closing their browser and again going to your site to rate, but maybe with the session you can create a time stamp meaning, that you can receive a rate from the same compute on two conditions: 1, if the browser has been closed 2, if the last rate made was about 20 minutes ago.

Comment: Feel free to ask more if you need, in the mean time I will paste this as an answer so the question can be resolved. But, wait and see if you can get a better suggestions, from other users.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the IP is most reliable since cookies expire. The other method is to create an account :)

Comment: lets say a few people who are on the same network like at a university or school. One person uses the rate up button, does that mean the rest of the people on the same network cant press the rate up too? :S

Comment: if i was to do this the IP way

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible to use cookies, but have in mind that they can be tampered with. There is no way to be certain when the user is not registered and logged in.